# Write list to csv file c#

Tags: c#, csv, io

Imagine i have 2 lists filled with values. I want all the elements from the first list, written into the first column, all the elements from the second list written into the second column and so on.

If both list have the same size, this works fine:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Count(); i++)
 {
      var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", valueArray.ElementAt(i), secondValueArray.ElementAt(i));
      sw.Write(newLine);
 }
```

My problem is that if the lists have different sizes, code fails with out of range exception obviously. I tried adding ',' between columns but it's not working.

Comment: you need to check to see what the length of one of the lists is and see if it is the same count as the variable I in your for loop. if not, continue writing that column otherwise do not.

Comment: You could just fill each list with blanks to make them all the same length, then do what you've already done.

Comment: Filling it with blank or -1 values it's not an option since it may desorient the users.

Comment: Your list is of which type?

Comment: Just a simple ArrayList with int values.

Comment: Hint: Do not read/write CSV manually, edge cases will devour your flesh. Consider using [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Comment: your for loop will not handle secondValueArray > first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `ElementAt` you should use `ElementAtOrDefault` :

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx) it

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default
>   value if the index is out of range.

Comment: It's not the same solution. The list content remains the same which is not the case when you fill up the list.

Comment: @ZackBogdan what you exactly want ?

Comment: ElementAtOrDefault works, but the default  value is 0 and is filling me the remaining values with 0. How can i change the default value to "" ?

Comment: I just wrote my own extension method and the default value is "". Thank you w.b & all.



    static String ElementAtOrDefault<T>(List<T> list, int index, String defaultValue)
        {
            return index >= 0 && index < list.Count ? list[index].ToString() : "";
        }

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List<int?> valueArray = new List<int?>();
List<int?> secondValueArray = new List<int?>();

//... fill lists
valueArray.Add( 1 );
valueArray.Add(2);
valueArray.Add(3);

secondValueArray.Add( 4 );

while (valueArray.Count > secondValueArray.Count)
    secondValueArray.Add(null);

while (secondValueArray.Count > valueArray.Count)
    valueArray.Add(null);

for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Count(); i++)
{
    var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", valueArray.ElementAt(i), secondValueArray.ElementAt(i));
    Console.WriteLine(newLine);
}

;
```

Result :

```
1,4
2,
3,
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, use ElementAtOrDefault(). And check which array is the longest one. Furthermore, you might want to write an empty string instead of NULL if there's no value.

```
 int count = Math.Max(firstArray.Count(), secondArray.Count());

 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
      var value1 = firstArray.ElementAtOrDefault(i) ?? String.Empty;
      var value2 = secondArray.ElementAtOrDefault(i) ?? String.Empty;

      var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", value1, value2);
      sw.Write(newLine);
 }
```